# Adding draggable and ondragstart to a span created by an execCommand

Tags: javascript, html

How would I go about adding attributes draggable and ondragstart to the span that this execCommand makes?

The outcome should be like this

```
<span draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"> <span>
```

Here is the execCommand

```
function color(){
  document.execCommand('styleWithCSS', false, true);
  document.execCommand('foreColor', false, "#9900cc");
}
```

All Solutions must be in Native Javascript no Jquery please.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: a quack look up at google come up with this https://github.com/Shopify/draggable/blob/master/scripts/test/helper.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Figured it out.
I added this to get the span.

```
 window.getSelection().focusNode.parentNode
```

Then set my attributes.

Full Function

```
 function color(){
 document.execCommand('styleWithCSS', false, true);
 document.execCommand('foreColor', false, "#9900cc");
 var selectedElement = window.getSelection().focusNode.parentNode;
 selectedElement.setAttribute("draggable", 'true');
 selectedElement.setAttribute("ondragstart", 'drag(event)');
 }
```